# how to place UILabel behind SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, skspritenode

i am trying to place a UILabel behind a SKSpriteNode. but what ever i try the label stays in front of the SpriteNode. z-index doesn't work and .movetoback also doesn't work.

could someone explain me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `UILabel` as a subview of `SKView` and adjust its position accordingly.

E.g. the following creates a white square sprite with an UILabel in front of it:

```
scene = SKScene(size: spriteView.bounds.size)
scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

let sprite = SKSpriteNode(
    color: SKColor.whiteColor(),
    size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
)

scene.addChild(sprite)

spriteView.presentScene(scene)

let frame = CGRect(
    x: spriteView.bounds.midX - 50,
    y: spriteView.bounds.midY - 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 100)

label = UILabel(frame: frame)
label.textAlignment = .Center
label.text = "Ook"

spriteView.addSubview(label)
```

P.S. I can not understand why would you want to use `UILabel` while `SpriteKit` has `SKLabelNode` which does practically the same but can be a part of the scene, so that will make your life easier in terms of adjusting positions.

Comment: `SKLabelNode` does not support text wrapping so this could be a compelling reason to use UILabel especially if it does not need any physics